# Why do I get a 403 error in Firefox but not in IE?

Tags: firefox, video, mp4

Going to http://teamtreehouse.com/ in IE 9.0.8112 the video on the right comes up and shows the still image. You click the image, and it plays fine.

I have Firefox 18.0.1 as my primary browser. When I go to that site, the still picture does not show, nor will the video play if you click on it. If I go to that page, and look at firebug, I see some "403 Forbidden" errors.

I thought this might be an mp4 issue, but I was able to watch mp4 video on another site. (QuickTime in browser plugin)

Looking for any suggestions to get this working in Firefox or how to troubleshoot this further.

**Update:**
In the error console I see a lot of "Warning: Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped." warnings and I see errors similar to "Error: [Exception... "'Image HTTP->HTTPS redirection to https://a248.e.akamai.net/...3cf7.png' " but nothing relating to video.

Comment: Works for me. Does the Error Console (Ctrl + Shift + J, clear the console and reload the page) show anything? Do you have another browser you can try? Have you tried a hard-refresh (Ctrl+F5)?

Answer (score 1):

The picture appears for me using Firefox.  It may be due to some add-on or configuration setting in your Firefox profile.  Try [creating a new Firefox profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) and checking the site using that profile.